# Redux: making sharing component trigger unique redux path depends on parent component

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is my scenario: I have a feed with list of questions. In each question, I have a upvote button for upvoting this question.

So I will design an upvote button component sharing between other question components. When clicking to this button, button will trigger an event to server. method signature sometime such as:

```
func upvote(questionOwnerId, upvoteUserId) { ... }
```

After upvoting, upvote will dispatch an event for redux handle and update state respectively. So upvote button will always display latest state. (how many upvoted users for that question).

This is my problem: I don't know how to make **sharing** component (upvote component), after calling method to server then trigger **unique** redux path on redux tree.

I have a solution for this: Upvote component will receive following parameters:

- total number of upvote.
- question's user id.
- **redux path.**

Then upvote function and Reducer will use redux path for update state on redux tree respectively. Does this method works well and look clean for project ? Or is there any "true" way for my problem?

**@Edit:** Redux path for example: `feeds.item.questionList.question[0]` for question component at 0 index. `feeds.item.questionList.question[1]` for question component at 1 index ... so Reducer can understand how to update redux tree.

Comment: what do you mean by `redux-path`?

Comment: For example: `feeds.questionList.question[0]` for upvote button in question[0].  So function will use above path for updating redux tree.

Comment: @Sag1v I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such shared component can be done by just receiving the proper `props` and passing a generic `onClick` events.

For example, let say we create component named `<Question />` and it will the props:

1. `votes` - to display current number of votes.
2. `onUpvote` - as a click event for the up-vote button.
3. `onDownvote` - as a click event for the down-vote button.
4. `id` - it needs the `id` in order to pass it to the parent's
   function.
5. `question` - The value of the question to display.

Now, your parent component will take a list of `questions` from the `redux-store` and will `.map` on it and will return for each question a `<Question />` component with the respective props (`id`, `votes` and `question`).
As for the `onUpVote` and `onDownVote` you will pass functions that created in the parent. These functions will dispatch actions and that will handled by your reducer which will return the new state, this will trigger a re-render with new data to show.

I've created a simple example, note that i can't use `redux` here so i managed the state inside the `App` component, but i mentioned in comments where you can dispatch actions and what logic should go inside the reducers.

```js
const questionsList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    votes: 2,
    question: "whats up"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    votes: -1,
    question: "whats the time"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    votes: 0,
    question: "where are you"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    votes: 7,
    question: "who are you"
  }
];

class Question extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onUpvote = this.onUpvote.bind(this);
    this.onDownvote = this.onDownvote.bind(this);
  }

  onUpvote() {
    const { id, onUpvote } = this.props;
    onUpvote(id);
  }

  onDownvote() {
    const { id, onDownvote } = this.props;
    onDownvote(id);
  }

  render() {
    const { votes, question } = this.props;
    const voteClassName = `votes ${votes < 0 ? 'low' : 'high'}`;
    return (
      <div className="question-wrapper">
        <div className="buttons-wrapper">
          <button className="button" onClick={this.onUpvote}>+</button>
          <div className={voteClassName}>{votes}</div>
          <button className="button" onClick={this.onDownvote}>-</button>
        </div>
        <div className="question">{question}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      questions: questionsList
    };

    this.onUpvote = this.onUpvote.bind(this);
    this.onDownvote = this.onDownvote.bind(this);
  }

  onUpvote(id) {
    const { questions } = this.state;
    // you can dispatch an action here
    // and instead of doing this logic in here you can do it in your reducer
    const nextState = questions.map(question => {
      if (question.id != id) {
        return question;
      }

      return {
        ...question,
        votes: question.votes + 1
      };
    });

    this.setState({ questions: nextState });
  }

  onDownvote(id) {
    const { questions } = this.state;
    // you can dispatch an action here
    // and instead of doing this logic in here you can do it in your reducer
    const nextState = questions.map(question => {
      if (question.id != id) {
        return question;
      }

      return {
        ...question,
        votes: question.votes - 1
      };
    });

    this.setState({ questions: nextState });
  }


  render() {
    const { questions } = this.state; // get the questions via props (redux store)
    return (
      <div>
        {questions.map(q => (
          <Question
            id={q.id}
            question={q.question}
            votes={q.votes}
            onUpvote={this.onUpvote}
            onDownvote={this.onDownvote}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.question-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #333;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.buttons-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button{
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.question{
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.high{
  color: #3cba54;
}

.low{
  color: #db3236;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. this solution has one drawback: maybe I need to upvote for question in another page (ProfilePage ...), I should to write again function "onUpvote(id)", and this will duplicate code. I want to prevent this situation also

Comment: Not exactly, if you are using `redux` you would use the same `reducer` and `action`. if your are using internal `react` state then this kind of `state` should be lifted up anyway. Remember, some components should be focused on how things looks, other components should decide how things work. keep the separation of concern principle. you should read [this article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) by dan abramov (creator of `redux` and works in the `react` team)

Comment: for example, upvote in profile page will be: "profilePage.questions[0].total_upvotes". upvote in feeds page will be: "feedPage.questions[0].total_upvotes". I means (due to my project architecture), each page will always have different redux path. So I cannot use same reducer (without further information such as path to a question object) for different pages. So I will need to write two functions: a function upvotes question in feeds page, and a function upvotes question in profile page. --> That is why I mean "duplicate code". They are mostly same code, just a "little tiny" difference.

Comment: `reducers` are just functions, any abstraction you can do with your "normal" functions you can do with your `reducer`. all you need to remember is to keep them _pure_ functions. same `reducer` can "listen" to multiple action types.